# Is it possible to require authentication to start server? (NodeJS/Express)

Tags: node.js, express

I am making a home web server that serves html over the LAN. I am looking for a way to only have to authenticate once (i.e. when starting the server) and have everyone on the LAN be able to access the html without having to authenticate.

Is this possible?

Comment: _"I am looking for a way to only have to authenticate once (i.e. when starting the server)"_ - Why not just run your node server and leave the auth part if client-server requests wouldn't require any auth anyway?

Comment: I'd like to be able to control who gets to start the server. I'm not worried about who gets to use the service once it has been started.

Comment: are you running the server on windows, linux, virtual machine?